# adding UIView to UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to add a Button or a label to a `UIView` and add it to my `UIViewController`. I did the following but it only crashed the program.

```
UIView *myview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 0, 300)] ;
[myview addSubview:myButton];

[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

The code crashes. Why is that?

Comment: "The code crashes." is not helpful. Please edit the question and tell us on what line your app crashes (use breakpoints and step through your code) and what the actual error message is.

Comment: the crash should display a message. there several possible reasons

Comment: Per the previous comments, please add a crash log so we can see where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You set your myview's width to 0.
You sure you created "myButton"?
You create myview but you add my**V**iew as subview. Is there any warning?

Comment: I added width to 0 is a mistake. it should be 100. I need `myView` to take up the entire screen. So how should i add it (if not to use `subView`)?

Comment: you can set myView's frame as the view's frame you want to put myview in.
[myView setFrame:biggerView.frame];

Answer (score 1):

The first step you need to take is:

- Make Sure you have allocated & initialized UIButton object with "initWithFrame" method.
- provide a width to your UIView in "initWithframe" method, So that it can be seen.
- Now use your [self.view addSubview:myView];

Please let me know if it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
//Assuming that myview should have the size of the main view:
UIView *myview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[myview addSubview:myButton]; //Whatever ...

[self.view addSubview:myview]; //There was a typo in this line
```

Answer (score 1):

**If this code block is in the init or loadView of viewcontroller, this will crash.
Make sure you have created a view for view controller in this case before adding views to self.view**

```
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
self.view = aView;
[aView release];

myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init....
.....

UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 0, 300)] ;
[myView addSubview:myButton];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the view with the following:

[myview setNeedsDisplay];

and remove the second call to addSubView (which is probably causing the crash):

<s>[self.view addSubview:myView];</s>